# I am looking for a regression formula to calculate a polar curve that goes through a set of points analogous to linear regression, how do I do this?

Tags: regression, circular-statistics

Suppose you have an arbitrary set of points in a two dimensional space, what is the "curve of best fit" not line of best fit that can be used to model the data?

Comment: you may be interested in "nonlinear least squares"

Comment: Are your points distinguished as an "independent" variable $x$ and a "dependent" variable $y$, and you are looking for a function $f$ such that $y\approx f(x)$? Or are you looking for a parameterized curve $g: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(x,y)\approx g(t)$? "Polar" suggests, to me, the latter.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Nathan.  One way (out of many) is to connect the points with line segments (or any other curve) in any order you please.  The generality of this solution demonstrates you need to supply additional requirements on the curve in order to solve this problem.